# Resetting pointer to an array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am sending 5 bytes of data from a Rasp. Pi and receiving them via a dsPIC30F microcontroller using UART. I can receive the data correctly and set the MAXCNT register to the value desired. The problem arises when I try to send a second value. The value in newResBuffer[] will not change after the first data read.

I am a beginner when it comes to pointers/arrays, but I suspect that my issue may lie with my method of resetting my pointer. I have tried many different ways of this with no success. Am I performing this step correctly?

```
#include <string.h>

char newResBuffer[10];
char *nR = newResBuffer;
char *nRreset = NULL;
char rxRead = 0;
int newRes = 0;
int newResFlag = 0;
int j = 0;

int main(void)
{
  nRreset = nR;    // set reset point at the beginning of newResBuffer[]

  while(1)
  {
    if(U1STAbits.URXDA)  // check if there is data available
    {
      rxRead = U1RXREG & 0xFF;  //read data from UART receive register
      *nR = rxRead;    //store data to first byte of newResBuffer[]
      nR++;            // increment pointer
      j++;

      if(j > 4)
      {
        *nR = '\0';        // null terminate the string
        newResFlag = 1;    // set the flag that new value is ready to be set
        j = 0;             // reset count variable

      }//if(j>4)

    }//if(U1STAbits.URXDA)

    if(newResFlag)         // has flag been set?
    {
      sscanf(newResBuffer, "%d", &newRes);    // convert string received to an int
      MAXCNT = (newRes * 2) - 1;   // set MAXCNT register to new value
      nR = nRreset;                // reset pointer to start of newResBuffer[]
      newResFlag = 0;              // reset flag

    }//if(newResFlag)
  }//while(1)

return 0;
}//main()
```

I did some testing with diagnostic LEDs and it looks like newResBuffer[ ] keeps being reset to the first value I send it. I have even tried re-initializing the array to all 0's after setting the new MAXCNT value to no avail.

Comment: Not sure `sscanf(newResBuffer, "%d", &newRes);   ` is doing what you want it to do and you have an infinite `while` loop

Comment: Infinite while loop is what I was shooting for. As for the sscanf(), I was hoping to take the string of chars (ex. newResBuffer = {'1','2','3','4','5','\0'}) and convert it into an int (ex. 12345). Is this the wrong way of of doing that?

Comment: Show declarations of variables. Currently you're `sscanf`ing from `newResBuffer` instead of `nR-4`.

Comment: @gudok I changed to sscanf(nR-5, "%d", &newRes)... still not working correctly.

Comment: This assignment `nR = nRreset;` makes `nR` point to NULL. This means that when reading first byte of second value you are dereferencing NULL pointer. I suppose that you meant `nr = newResBuffer`.

Comment: First line of `main()` is `nRreset = nR` so when I get to the `nR = nRreset` line it is setting it back to newResBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of resetting the pointer is correct, although there are some easier ways to achieve it. I assume that your error must be somehow related setting the MAXCNT register or reading new data from the receive register. I don't know enough about the Raspberry Pi microcontroller to help you there, but perhaps you need to flush or refresh the MAXCNT register before updating it to a new value?

I tested your code by replacing the Raspberry Pi specific register usage with standard C functions for reading from stdin and printing to `stdout`. It's easy to test and see that the part of the code that involves receiving an individual char digit, storing it in a string buffer, converting that buffer to an int, and reusing the buffer, are all correct. Here's my code showing that the values are read in correctly and showing some additional information to confirm that the buffer address is incremented and reset correctly:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char newResBuffer[10];
char *nR = newResBuffer;
char *nRreset = NULL;
char rxRead = 0;
int newRes = 0;
int newResFlag = 0;
int j = 0;

int main(void)
{
    nRreset = nR;

    /* Printing out initial memory addresses */
    printf("newResBuffer address: %p\n", (void *) newResBuffer);
    printf("Initial nRreset address: %p\n", (void *) nRreset);
    printf("Initial nR address: %p\n\n", (void *) nR);

    while(1)
    {
        /* Using rand() % 2 to simulate data availability */
        if(rand() % 2)
        {
            /* Using getc() instead of the register to read individual digits */
            rxRead = getc(stdin);
            printf("rxRead: %c saved to nR address %p\n", rxRead, (void *) nR);
            *nR = rxRead;
            nR++;
            j++;

            if(j > 4)
            {
                *nR = '\0';
                newResFlag = 1;
                j = 0;
            }
        }

        if(newResFlag)
        {
            sscanf(newResBuffer, "%d", &newRes);
            /* Printing newRes and MAXCNT instead of setting the register */
            printf("newRes: %d\n", newRes);
            printf("MAXCNT: %d\n", (newRes * 2) - 1);
            printf("nR address before reset: %p\n", (void *) nR);
            nR = nRreset;
            printf("nR address after reset: %p\n\n", (void *) nR);
            newResFlag = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output when tested with the input "**7594819432**" is:

> newResBuffer address: **0x10779f060**
>   Initial nRreset address: 0x10779f060
>   Initial nR address: 0x10779f060
>
> rxRead: 7 saved to nR address **0x10779f060**
>   rxRead: 5 saved to nR address 0x10779f061
>   rxRead: 9 saved to nR address 0x10779f062
>   rxRead: 4 saved to nR address 0x10779f063
>   rxRead: 8 saved to nR address 0x10779f064
>   newRes: **75948**
>   MAXCNT: 151895
>   nR address before reset: **0x10779f065**
>   nR address after reset: **0x10779f060**
>
> rxRead: 1 saved to nR address **0x10779f060**
>   rxRead: 9 saved to nR address 0x10779f061
>   rxRead: 4 saved to nR address 0x10779f062
>   rxRead: 3 saved to nR address 0x10779f063
>   rxRead: 2 saved to nR address 0x10779f064
>   newRes: **19432**
>   MAXCNT: 38863
>   nR address before reset: **0x10779f065**
>   nR address after reset: **0x10779f060**

I mentioned earlier that there are some easier ways for you to reset the pointer. You can actually do it without using `nRreset`; since the base address for `newResBuffer` never changes, you can simply reset it with `nR = newResBuffer`.

An even easier way to do it would be not to use a moving pointer at all and simply use the variable `j` you already have in your code to index `newResBuffer`.

You can also use `atoi()` or `strtol()` instead of `sscanf()` to convert the string buffer to an `int` (or `long`).

Here's a simpler version of the code which achieves the same thing:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char newResBuffer[10];
    char rxRead = 0;
    int newRes = 0;
    int newResFlag = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (1) {
        /* if (U1STAbits.URXDA) { */
        if (rand() % 2) {
            /* rxRead = U1RXREG & 0xFF; */
            rxRead = getc(stdin);
            newResBuffer[j++] = rxRead;

            if (j > 4) {
                newResBuffer[j] = '\0';
                newResFlag = 1;
                j = 0;
            }
        }

        if (newResFlag) {
            newRes = atoi(newResBuffer);
            /* MAXCNT = (newRes * 2) - 1; */
            printf("newRes: %d\n", newRes);
            printf("MAXCNT: %d\n", (newRes * 2) - 1);
            newResFlag = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I eliminated using pointers at all and just referenced the array locations with counter variable j. Looks like my original code worked as it should (found another error within my microcontroller code, the receive buffer was getting 1byte too much data and I never cleared the overflow error flag), but I feel my updated code is much smoother now. Thanks!!